# CMake finds fftw library but cannot link

Tags: linker, cmake, ros

I have problem linking the fftw library using cmake. I use a findFFTW.cmake file in order to find the library. I know this is successfully finding the library because I set the REQUIRED flag to be true for finding the library and the make process goes through fine.

Despite linking it with my executable, I am still getting undefined reference errors. Some related posts, whose solutions I have tried.

[Undefined reference to "function name from external library"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155566/undefined-reference-to-function-name-from-external-library)

http://answers.ros.org/question/171326/catkin-linking-order-undefined-reference-to-symbol/

**Updates**

Thanks to ComicSansMS, the CMake below should now model the dependencies correctly.

**CMake file of project (updated 3/7)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gist_extractor)

## Find catkin macros and libraries

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  image_transport
  cv_bridge
  sensor_msgs
  cmake_modules
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(FFTW REQUIRED)


###########
## Build ##
###########

## Set GIST variables for building library
set(GIST_PATH /home/andy/Development/lear_gist-1.2)

## Specify additional locations of header files
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GIST_PATH} ${FFTW_INCLUDES})

## Declare a gist library
add_library(gist SHARED ${GIST_PATH}/standalone_image.c ${GIST_PATH}/gist.c) # THIS IS NOT BEING BUILT 
target_link_libraries(gist ${FFTW_LIBRARIES})

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
#MESSAGE( STATUS "GIST_LIBRARY_PATH: " ${GIST_PATH})

## Declare a C++ executable
add_executable(gist_extractor src/gist_extractor.cpp)
target_link_libraries(gist_extractor ${catkin_LIBRARIES} gist)
```

**EDITS 2**

We now have a linking error if we use the above CMake file. Specifically the make process fails when I try running

```
target_link_libraries(gist_extractor ${catkin_LIBRARIES} gist)
```

I have a couple of observations. Firstly, my gist library is being built correctly based on the below console messages.

```
Linking C shared library /home/andy/Projects/ROS/robot_ws/devel/lib/libgist.so
[ 80%] Built target gist
Scanning dependencies of target gist_extractor
[100%] Building CXX object 
`gist_extractor/CMakeFiles/gist_extractor.dir/src/gist_extractor.cpp.o
```

But we can see that there are undefined reference errors when we try to link our executable with the gist library.

```
Linking CXX executable gist_extractor
: undefined reference to `color_gist_scaletab'
```

Here's why I don't understand why this is occurring. In gist_extractor.cpp, I have included the header file that includes the 'color_gist_scaletab' function. Specifically, this 'color_gist_scaletab is in defined in 'gist.h' and implemented in 'gist.c'. I would think that building my library gist should give me access to 'color_gist_scaletab'. I have posted the relevant files below.

*gist.h*

```
#ifndef GIST_H_INCLUDED
#define GIST_H_INCLUDED

#include "standalone_image.h"

/*! Graylevel GIST for various scales. Based on Torralba's Matlab
 * implementation. http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/code/spatialenvelope/
 *
 * Descriptor size is  w*w*sum(n_orientations[i],i=0..n_scale-1)
 *
 *    @param src Source image
 *    @param w Number of bins in x and y axis
 */

float *bw_gist_scaletab(image_t *src, int nblocks, int n_scale, const int *n_orientations);

/*! @brief implementation of grayscale GIST descriptor.
 * Descriptor size is w*w*(a+b+c)
 *
 *    @param src Source image
 *    @param w Number of bins in x and y axis
 */
float *bw_gist(image_t *scr, int nblocks, int a, int b, int c);

/*! @brief implementation of color GIST descriptor.
 *
 *    @param src Source image
 *    @param w Number of bins in x and y axis
 */

float *color_gist(color_image_t *src, int nblocks, int a, int b, int c);
/*! Color GIST for various scales. Based on Torralba's Matlab
 * implementation. http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/code/spatialenvelope/  */

float *color_gist_scaletab(color_image_t *src, int nblocks, int n_scale, const int *n_orientations);


#endif
```

*gist_extractor.cpp*

```
// color_gist_scaletab is defined in gist.h
// I'm including relevant header file 
#include "/home/andy/Development/lear_gist-1.2/gist.h"

//SOME MORE STUFF
// This is where I call the function
float *gist_descriptor = color_gist_scaletab(im, nblocks, n_scale, orientations_per_scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did not model your dependencies correctly.

You use fftw from inside `gist.c`, which is part of the `gist` library target.

However, that target does not have a dependency to fftw, only the downstream target `gist_extractor` has. This is a recipe for trouble, especially in static builds, where toolchains are often picky about the order in which libraries appear on the linker command line.

Add fftw as a dependency to `gist`:

```
target_link_libraries(gist ${FFTW_LIBRARIES})
```

Also, there is no need to do this:

```
add_dependencies(gist_extractor gist)
target_link_libraries(gist_extractor ${GIST_PATH}/libleargist.a)
```

If both targets are built as part of the same project, simply do:

```
target_link_libraries(gist_extractor gist)
```

By using the target name instead of hardcoding the output file, you not only make your build script more portable, but also allow CMake to better track the inter-target dependencies for you.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the comments. This was beyond helpful!

Comment: The way you modeled dependencies makes a lot of sense. After incorporating your suggestions, I'm realizing that my library "gist" is not being built. As a result I still get undefined symbol errors. Do you have any ideas why this might be the case and how I can fix it? It was precisely this issue which forced me to hardcode the libleargist.a. I updated code in my original post to better explain this.

Comment: @AndyLee Are you sure that `gist` is not being built? Because there is nothing in the code you posted that would cause this. Try running `make gist` from the command line. You shouldn't get any complaints.

Comment: Apologies, gist is actually being built because I can find the libgist.so file. The real problem is that there is a linker error when I try target_link_libraries(gist_extractor gist ...). I get undefined reference errors for my executable gist_extractor. I include the relevant header files in gist_extractor.cpp and I'm modeling dependencies correctly now so I don't understand why this problem occurs. I updated the post under EDITS2 with relevant code. Any help would be immensely appreciated.